# Segmented Control Text Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

How can I save in a NSString the text of the segment I clicked? Now I only obtain the index.

```
- (IBAction)segmentedControlShortcuts:(id)sender {

NSString *shortcutText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)segmentedControlShortcuts.selectedSegmentIndex];
NSLog(@"%@", shortcutText);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sender will be the `UISegmentedControl`, so you just need to cast it and use `titleForSegmentAtIndex`.

```
- (IBAction)segmentedControlShortcuts:(id)sender {
    UISegmentedControl *control = (UISegmentedControl *)sender;
    NSString *shortcutText = [control titleForSegmentAtIndex:control.selectedSegmentIndex];
}
```

Comment: It's even easier if you change the method to `- (IBAction)segmentedControlShortcuts:(UISegmentedControl *)control {`. No need for the cast.